# SharePoint 2010 Workflow Active Directory Group Enumeration?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, active-directory

I am working on sending mail via workflow and would like for list inserts by a particular user, say 
user1, to send mail to a particular AD group, say TestGroup1. Similarly, for user2 to userN. 
Is it possible to determine AD group membership inside a workflow?

Thnaks in Advance,
Naresh.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by adding emailId of manager in manager's group which exists in AD and sent mail through workflow..so that the mail can sent to user(who adds an item in a list) and that Manager Email ID..